Video Streaming with GSM/GPRS SIM800 Modules
I want to stream video footage collected from a camera to a webserver using a Raspberry Pi and internet without the use of Wireless LAN.
I was originally thinking of just connecting a USB modem with a SIM card to the Raspberry Pi to connect to the internet and stream the video.

I was wondering if it is possible to use a GSM/GPRS module as a replacement for a Modem.
And also what are the possible advantages and disadvantages of using either option?

Thank you in advance.

it is unclear what you are asking ... anything that gives an internet connection is a modem

It's possible to use the SIM800 Module instead of the USB modem.
